# Reshape Breaks Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im working on a word embedding model, which keeps breaking when I try to add a final `Reshape`.  Below is the model with the `Reshape` that throws:

`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

I can't figure out why these dimensions don't add up.

```
embedding_size = 50
input_size = 46
# Both inputs are 1-dimensional
ingredients = Input(
     name='ingredients',
    shape=(input_size,)
)
documents = Input(
    name='documents',
    shape=(input_size,)
)


ingredients_embedding = Embedding(name='ingredients_embedding',
                                  input_dim=training_size,
                                  output_dim=embedding_size)(ingredients)

# Embedding the document (shape is (None, 46, 50))
document_embedding = Embedding(name='documents_embedding',
                               input_dim=training_size,
                               output_dim=embedding_size)(documents)

# Merge the layers with a dot product along the second axis (shape is (None, 46, 46))
merged = Dot(name='dot_product', normalize=True, axes=2)([ingredients_embedding, document_embedding])

# ~ This like breaks ~
# Reshape to be a single number (shape will be (None, 1))
merged = Reshape(target_shape=(1,))(merged) # <-- ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged


m = Model(inputs=[ingredients, documents], outputs=merged)
m.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse')

return m
```

Comment: Why your inputs are of shape `(46,)`?

Comment: Each input is a fixed-length sentence of 46 words

Comment: I put the integers there for readability

Comment: Then your `document_embedding` should be `(None, 46, embedding_size)`

Comment: 46 is the embedding size.  The `document_embedding` shape should be `(None, 1, 46)`, no?

Comment: For some reason, the shape after the Embedding layer is `(None, 46, 46)`

Comment: the first 46 is your sentence length, the second 46 is your embedding_size. So the inputs to your `Dot` are two matrices of shape (46,46).

Comment: I see.  How can I make these dimensions end up matching up?

Comment: So you want to make the document a vector rather than a matrix before feeding into `Dot`?

Comment: If you want to compute doc similarity, you could sum `document_embedding` along the last axis before feeding into `Dot`.

Comment: I updated my code to include the correct embedding/input variables.  I simply want to code before `Reshape` and after it to work.  I have vetted this architecture but I cant get this implementation to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189639/discussion-between-redress-and-keineahnung2345).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typically way to represent a document as a vector is to sum the `document_embedding` matrix along the sentence dimension.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dot, Reshape, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

embedding_size = 50
input_size = 46

ingredients = Input(
    name='ingredients',
    shape=(input_size,)
)
documents = Input(
    name='documents',
    shape=(input_size,)
)

ingredients_embedding = Embedding(name='ingredients_embedding',
                                  input_dim=input_size,
                                  output_dim=embedding_size)(ingredients)

document_embedding = Embedding(name='documents_embedding',
                               input_dim=input_size,
                               output_dim=embedding_size)(documents)

#sum over the sentence dimension
ingredients_embedding = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=-2))(ingredients_embedding)
#sum over the sentence dimension
document_embedding = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=-2))(document_embedding)

merged = Dot(name='dot_product', normalize=True, axes=-1)([ingredients_embedding, document_embedding])

merged = Reshape(target_shape=(1,))(merged) 

m = Model(inputs=[ingredients, documents], outputs=merged)
m.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse')
m.summary()
```

`document_embedding` is of shape `(None, input_size, embedding_size)`, so `-2` is the second last axis, which is the axis of sentence dimension.

Comment: Im also getting this:

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 460 into shape (1,46)`

Comment: Can you paste the full code generating that error in your question?

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I fixed it.  There was a pesky reshape somehere

Comment: I had a random `shape` issue in some Numpy code which caused the problem.  Nothing related to Keras

Comment: It seems `training_size` serves as the same role as `input_size`, so I've remove it.

Comment: `training_size` is the number of samples in the entire training set, `input_size` is the length of the sentence, FYI

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you should use `input_size` in `Embedding` rather than `training_size`.

Comment: I see, makes sense.  Thank you so much once again for your help!

Comment: So `training_size` shouldnt show up anywhere in the network?